# Why is this JSON returning an empty string?

Tags: php, json

My JSON should positively bring back a value. And a single value only... But when trying to decode and dispay, it shows up emty, like this ''.

Here's the code on the page:

```
 $schoolid = $_GET['schoolid'];
 $json_skool = file_get_contents("http://www.examscan.us/api/webapi.php?
 Oper2=getschoolname&schoolid=" . $schoolid);
 $json_skool = json_decode($json_skool);
 $skool = $json_skool->SchoolName;

 echo "<table><tr><th colspan=6>" .  $skool . " - Student List </th></tr>"
```

And this is how it appears:

-- Student List

My question here.. Does anyone notice something wrong in the syntax? Or the way I use it?

Comment: Can you show us what the raw JSON looks like please.

Comment: @RachelB what is the result of `var_dump($json_skool)`

Comment: If you go to the URL in your web browser you should get it and can just copy/paste from there

Comment: Here: {"data":[{"SchoolName":"Manhattanville School of Business"}]}

Comment: Phiter, that's exactly what I did...

Comment: @RachelB can you try like this .$json_skool->data->SchoolName;

Comment: actually it would be `$json_skool->data[0]->SchoolName`

Comment: Yeahhh! You guys rock!!!! Thanx Pamblam. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this code :

```
$skool = $json_skool->data[0]->SchoolName
```

Demo : https://eval.in/521902